# Socket-io not working on Android with React Native and Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket, socket.io, expo

In my application I have implemented real time with socket-io with an external server (https://api.xxxxx.com:300)

Currently it works perfectly for iOS, but Android never gets to connect to the server.

On the server, socket io is declared as follows

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {...};
var https = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var curl = require('http');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    ....
});

https.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

In my App.js File, I have to start the connection with the following code:

```
  // Initialize Socket IO:


global.socket = socketIO("https://api.xxxxx.com:3000", {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    forceNew: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 3000,
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
    jsonp: false
  });

  socket.connect();

  console.warn('First', JSON.stringify(socket['io']));

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.warn('Connect Correctly');
  });

  console.warn('Second', JSON.stringify(socket['io']));
```

As you can see, I print the state of the socket to see the readyStatus that at the moment First an Second always appears with readyStatus: "opening"

Later, I check the status of the socket in my application and a readyStatus: closed appears.

I remember that this only happens to me in Android, in iOS the operation is perfect and always ends with the connected state.

The versions that I have in my application are the following:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx-app",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "json-circular-stringify": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.5",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, add this to the client

```
const socket = io(baseUrl,{
transports: ['websocket'])}
```

source: [link](https://github.com/expo/socket-io-example/blob/master/app/main.js)